# ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for in neural network using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, mnist

I am trying to write a model to classify the handwritten digits from the mnist dataset. I am currently using a model that looks like this:

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),input_shape = (28,28,1),padding = "same"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),input_shape = (28,28,1),padding = "same"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),input_shape = (28,28,1),padding = "same"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),input_shape = (28,28,1),padding = "same"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),input_shape = (28,28,1),padding = "same"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (28,28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,'softmax')
])
```

Its supposed to be a convolutional deep neural network with 5 layers and I keep getting this error message on the last line of the model.

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling2d_9/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](dense_10/Sigmoid)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,4000].`
```

I don't understand the error or how to fix it. Can someone please help me? I already set the padding to "same" but it didn't fix it. I am also using google colab if that helps.

Comment: Your post isn't formatted in a helpful way - can you reformat with markdown code formatting? You encapsulate multiline code with \`\`\`code\`\`\`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably need here. To show your code your need to enclose it in four sequential special characters. The  character  `to use is the one to the left of 1 on your keyboard. Put 4 of these characters in a row. Then skip a line and enter code. When done with code create a new line. On it put four of those` characters in a row. This encapsulates your code show it will show up properly when you post your question. The formatted code for your posting is shown below.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([ 
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),input_shape = (28,28,1),padding = "same"), 
tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'), tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(), tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),input_shape = (28,28,1),padding = "same"), tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'), 
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(), 
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),input_shape = (28,28,1),padding = "same"), tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(), 
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),input_shape = (28,28,1),padding = "same"), tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'), 
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(), 
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),input_shape = (28,28,1),padding = "same"), tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'), 
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(), tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (28,28)), tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,'softmax') ] )
```

Its supposed to be a convolutional deep neural network with 5 layers and I keep getting this error message on the last line of the model. ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling2d_9/MaxPool}} = MaxPoolT=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]'

Answer (score 0):

In your keras model the `input_shape` argument is only needed for your first layer and initializes your network.

Because you use `MaxPooling2D`, your image is downsized by 2. If you want to understand your network, try `print(model.summary())`. So at a point, you downsize your `1x1x4000` image by 2. Try to go less deeper in your network, for instance :

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),input_shape = (28,28,1),padding = "same"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),padding = "same"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),padding = "same"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),padding = "same"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(4000,activation = 'sigmoid'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,'softmax')])
```

The structure looks like :

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_35 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 8)         80        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_39 (Dense)             (None, 28, 28, 4000)      36000     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_34 (MaxPooling (None, 14, 14, 4000)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_36 (Conv2D)           (None, 14, 14, 8)         288008    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_40 (Dense)             (None, 14, 14, 4000)      36000     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_35 (MaxPooling (None, 7, 7, 4000)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_37 (Conv2D)           (None, 7, 7, 8)           288008    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_41 (Dense)             (None, 7, 7, 4000)        36000     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_36 (MaxPooling (None, 3, 3, 4000)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_38 (Conv2D)           (None, 3, 3, 8)           288008    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_42 (Dense)             (None, 3, 3, 4000)        36000     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_37 (MaxPooling (None, 1, 1, 4000)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)          (None, 4000)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_43 (Dense)             (None, 10)                40010     
=================================================================
Total params: 1,048,114
Trainable params: 1,048,114
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Finally, your network is not well optimized, and I leave it to you to search for and try a better architecture.